# Incrementing/decrementing entirely a float type number

Tags: c++, increment, decrement

What I'm trying to do is to increment the entire float value, for example:

## Incrementing

> -0.09683964401

to:

> 1.09683964401

or:

> 1.09683964401

to:

> 2.09683964401

## Decrementing

> -0.09683964401

to:

> -1.09683964401

or:

> -1.09683964401

to:

> -2.09683964401

I know I would need to use a loop, but how would I do it?

This is what I tried:

```
(float)myFloatValue++;
```

which doesn't do what I actually need.

Comment: What does that code do that you don't need?

Comment: @nicomp should I use it in a loop? How should I do a loop? Replying to your question: it doesn't increment the entire float value.

Comment: Btw `-0.09 + 1` is not `1.09` but `0.91`...

Comment: You say "What I'm trying to do is to increment the entire float value,"  - but your examples show incrementing only the integer part; and leaving the absolute value of the floating part unchanged

Comment: I don't know what that means. "It doesn't increment the entire float value"? What, precisely, does it do? What does the entire code snippet look like?

Comment: @M.M **that was an example. Didn't want to use the calculator to increment everything**... My question was how could I increment the **entire** float value, so other than the integer part, the absolute value goes incremented too.

Comment: @xF00lProgram "incrementing the entire float value" on `-0.09683964401` gives `0.90316035599`

Comment: @M.M ok, in this case the first (integer) part doesn't changes. How could I integrate this in C++?

Comment: @xF00lProgram sorry I have no idea what you mean. Perhaps you could give some more examples.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour in your examples could be reproduced by:

```
void increment(float& f)
{
    if ( f > -1 && f < 0 )
        f = -f;
    ++f;
}

void decrement(float& f)
{
    if ( f > 0 && f < 1 )   // Presumably; you didn't show any examples in this range
        f = -f;
    --f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop to increment or decrement any number.Either use the ++ operator

```
myFloatValue++
```

or

```
myFloatValue = myFloatValue + 1
```

This will increment the entire number and not just the integer part.And if want to increment only the integer part then

```
myFloatValue = myFloatValue < 0 ? (-myFloatValue  + 1) : (myFloatValue +1);
```